# Custom views for cgridview based on role

Tags: php, yii

I want to filter my CgridView to only display has "student" role from Authassignment Model, I read some tutorials but none of them show this. 
Please help me, this is related to my thesis.

```
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    // 'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(

        'userID',
        'lastname',

        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); 

?>
```

[StudentView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbD5r.png)

Comment: Is the gridView for your Authassignment model? Or your User model?

Comment: it's from User model

Comment: you can refer this URL for role based access in YII : **http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please refer this as suggestion

I don't  know whats your `table structure` is but the best way of doing this may be. Create a `field` in `user table` named `user_role` and at the time of user creation insert value in this like `1 for admin 2 for student` and then you can easily get only student `role` by below method like

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new User('search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
      $model->user_role = 2;// for student role 
        if(isset($_GET['User']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```